# Deploying a react-native app but not on the app store or play store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-native, server

I've created a react-native app and I want to be able to show people it without having to start my javascript server and ruby rails server every time.

I don't want to upload it to the app store or play store as I don't think its ready yet. But I want to be able to show it in interviews without having to bring my laptop.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Just send them the APK? You could also use expo and publish it as unlisted. However, they would need the expo app on their phone with this case

Comment: How can I generate an APK from my react-native app? I'm a noob, so not entirely sure what an APK even is sorry

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android Is this my step by step?

Comment: The APK is build file for an android application. You can use android studio to build the app so that you can test it on your own device and send to others.

Comment: Yes that link is the gist of it

Comment: If you put your response as an answer I can mark it as solved

Answer (score 1):

You can just build the app with android studio and then save it on google drive or somewhere else, this way anyone can download it and install it, since it is not from play store your phone will only warn you that what you're installing is not from a trusted source but it will still install.

Answer (score 1):

You can use expo instead of just react native.
Register an account on expo and in your CLI you enter
`expo publish` to upload the latest version of your app and you will also be given a QR code.

Next install the expo app either on your Android or iOS, then scan the given QR code. And that's it...

**Edit**
Apparently expo made an update and the new command is
`npx expo publish`